# why iam getting worng username and pwd for correct things in php

Tags: php

this is my checklogin in database function

```
function CheckLoginInDB($username,$password)
{
    if(!$this->DBLogin())
    {
        $this->HandleError("Database login failed!");
        return false;
    }          
    $username = $this->SanitizeForSQL($username);
    $pwdmd5 = md5($password);
    $qry = "Select name, email from $this->tablename where username='$username' and password='$pwdmd5' and confirmcode='y'";

    $result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection);

    if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
    {
        $this->HandleError("Error logging in. The username or password does not match");
        return false;
    }

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


    $_SESSION['name_of_user']  = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['email_of_user'] = $row['email'];
    $_SESSION['user_name']=$row['username'];

    return true;
}
```

.......................................................................................
this is called in login.php as

```
if($fgmembersite->Login())
```

if this return true than user will be directed to login successful page.
but i dont why it is always returning false!and showing the error "Error logging in. The username or password does not match"...

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I also noticed that in your code, you call one method however, you show us a differently one ... I don't think that is right.

Try adding `or die(mysql_error())` to your line:

```
$result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection);
```

To become:

```
$result = mysql_query($qry,$this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

My guess is your query is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Due to this condition, if your query fails because of bad syntax you will still get the "Error logging in" message, which is bogus for a failed query:

```
 if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
```

Change to:

```
 if (!$result) {
     echo mysql_error();
 }
 else if (mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0) {
    // error logging in, non-matching user/pass
 }
```